# Using an array of index values to access a part of an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to find a way to access a part of an array with specific indexes, and the indexes are also in array. So, I have something like that:

```
var arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
var arrIndexes = [1, 3, 5];
```

And I'm searching for an easy way to use `arrIndexes` to access this specific part of `arr`, so that my output would be simply `['one', 'three', 'five']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with slightly less computational effort by using `Array.prototype.map()` instead:

```js
var arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
var arrIndexes = [1, 3, 5];

const res = arrIndexes.map(i=>arr[i])

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Good answer! This is optimal (y)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, I knew that there was something easy which I could not think of :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `Array.prototype.filter()` and `includes()` function. Try this-

```js
var arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
var arrIndexes = [1, 3, 5];

const res = arr.filter((item, index) => arrIndexes.includes(index));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can using reduce function like this

```
 let newAr=arr.reduce((prev,curr,idx,arr)=>{
    if(arrIndexes.includes(idx)){
        prev.push(arr[idx]);
    }
    return prev;
},[])
```